# How can i connect resources in Azure using System Managed identity?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I have deployed an app into Azure , namely a .net app and want to use the System Managed Identity feature in Azure, so as to not use username and password in my database connection strings.

I went to my App Service , named TestApp. For this app in the Configuration there is a connection string that has a username and password, like the following format:

So all i did was create the Identity and grant the database access to that managed identity unde Add Role Assignment and change the App Service connection string to the following:

```
 Server=<servername>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database>;Authentication=Active 
 Directory Default
```

But it doesnt connect at all Does the .net code need to change in regards to the way i connect to the db ?

Any ideas on what i may have missed

Comment: which nuget package are you using to connect to azure sql ? you need to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: When you mention connect to azure sql , do you mean how do i connect from within my .net code ?

Comment: using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
                    conn.Open();   and SqlConnection  is dervied from System.Data.SqlClient.       So does that mean that when i initially connect to the db i need to change or everywhere i connect to the azure db it needs to change ?

Comment: you need to use microsoft.data.sqlclient rather than system.data.sqlclient

Comment: so in other words , in the .net app I need to remove the nuget package System.Data.SqlClient and replace with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and resolve any errors ?  Its used in quite a few places in quite a few projects

Comment: Yeah you would need to do that. Give it a try in one proiject to see if that work for you first.

Comment: I tried to install the nuget package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient , and reference it , instead of the Systsme.Data.SqlClient, same error.